# How to add namedmodel to a RDF dataset

Tags: java, model, dataset, rdf, jena

When i want to add a namedModel to my dataset i get this type of error

```
the methode addNamedModel(String,Model) is undefined for the type Dataset
```

I use the following code :

```
Dataset dataset = DatasetFactory.create() ;
Model model1 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model1.add(subject, predicateSource, objectSource);
Model model2 = this.translator.getModel();
dataset.addNamedModel(g,model2 );
```

"g" is a String

Comment: Sounds like you have a version of Jena that does not have that method on the `Dataset` class, or you've accidentally imported some other `Dataset` class.  Is it `org.apache.jena.query.Dataset`?

Comment: this is what i imported com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Dataset
And i'm using jena 2.6.4

Comment: I don't know about the `com.hp.hpl` part... I believe Jena is now under Apache and the correct library and package is `org.apache.jena...`.  You may need to review your dependencies and update to the latest version  Not posting as an answer because I know nothing about Jena, this is just what I found in 3 minutes of Googling.

Answer (score 0):

Jena 2.6.4 was December 2010 and predates current RDF and SPARQL standards.

Back then, update operations like `addNamedModel` were on `DataSource`.

`DatasetFactory.create()` returned a `DataSource`.